# Drush cim: error "Table xyz already exists"

Tags: 8, drush

I'm trying to deploy a dev website to a dev server. When running `drush cim` on the dev server, drush ends with an error message:

> Table honeypot_user already exists

When running `drush cim` again right after that, the same error comes up again for a while with different table-names. The database does definitely not have these tables before running the config import.

What's the underlying problem and how can I solve that?

Using drush 8.1.17 on a Drupal 8.3.7 (both running offline and soon to be updated for security patches)

Comment: You should update core first - the problem might be caused by a bug that's been fixed

Comment: Same error after update. What's the best way to debug this?

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant but try:
`drush cr` before you `drush cim`.

Answer (score 1):

Like event said, and In my case, this was solved when the `drush cr` command is entered before `drush cim`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `drush cim --yes`

Same thing happened to me over the weekend. The

> --yes

flag seemed to fix the problem

Comment: This is crazy but this actually works! You saved my day.